# How to update background of page dynamically with Flickr API

Tags: javascript, jquery, flickr

**Edit**: Static source urls can be constructed for Flickr images.  Explanation: 
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.urls.html

---

I am making an ajax request to grab photos and I would like to parse this information in order to update the background of the page.

This is rough code:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=[API_KEY]&safe_search=&lat=' + geoLat + '&lon=' + geoLong + '&format=json&nojsoncallback=1',
        error: function() {
                 console.log('FlickerAPI Error');
               },
        success: function(data) {
          var photoID = data.photos.photo[0].id;
          var ownerID = data.photos.photo[0].owner;
          var backgroundImageUrl = 'http://www.flickr.com/photos/' + ownerID + '/' + photoID + '/';

          $('body').css('background-image','url(backgroundImageUrl)');
               },
        always: function() {
                console.log('finished flicker');
               }

});
```

When I log to the console this info, I get this error:
    GET http://localhost:4567/backgroundImageUrl 404 (Not Found).

But when I log out the backgroundImageUrl I get: http://www.flickr.com/photos/[the right photo id]/[the right user id]/ which if I follow the link, takes me to the page that I want.

I've searched the docs, and it looks like they don't pass a url attribute.

Is this a problem with using localhost?  Is there a better way to update the background with an image? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using the string literal `backgroundImageUrl` rather than using the contents of the variable (the actual url).  Because that string doesn't contain a host or protocol it thinks it is relative to the current request.

You need to append the value of the variable when making the url instead.

```
$('body').css('background-image','url(' + backgroundImageUrl + ')');
```

Comment: Ok, great. That solved the url problem.  It shows up correctly as an attribute to the body element.  However, the background doesn't change.  If I follow the link such as  https://www.flickr.com/photos/67021992@N05/18386545905/, it takes me to the picture page so I must be missing something.

Comment: That url is for the gallery page. You want the url that links directly to the image, not it's gallery page. You probably need to make a call to `getSizes` and use one of the source urls for the image in the results.

Comment: Ok, I thought as much.  Thanks for the help.